# Prevent marker from moving in QGIS when zooming

Tags: qgis, labeling, markers, zoom

I was wondering how I can prevent the movement of my markers when zooming out in QGIS.

I have this sample image of Auckland on a larger scale where everything seems to be ok:

[image]

Then I zoom out a little bit and everything starts moving:

[image]

Also when switching to the print layout everything gets into a new order. Probably I'm just missing something really obvious here...

Comment: Were is the symbol anchored/place is respect to the geometry?

Answer (score 6):

After @Erik’s comment, I found the answer quickly. I just missed that the Anchor point wasn't centred, so I just centered it and everything works fine!

[image]